# Triangular form question

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Problem: find a basis of $C^3$ such that the matrix of the transformation with respect to that basis is triangular 
$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}0&1&1\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$$

My work is : consider the dual transformation $A' = A^t$ . $A'$ has at least $1$ eigenvector, say $x$, there exists $1-D$ subspace $M$ invariant under $A'$, namely, the set of all multiple of $x$.
I got one of the eigenvalue is $1$, but I got stuck when I cannot find out the eigenvector for this eigenvalue.
$$A' - I = \left[\begin{matrix}-1&0&1\\1&-1&0\\1&1&-1\end{matrix}\right]$$
I cannot step up without this $M$. Appreciate any help

Comment: Hint: Move the first column to the last

Comment: @PVanchinathan nothing change when doing that.@Marc van Leeuwen I double checked, the matrix is correct.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection the linear transformation maps $e_2\mapsto e_1\mapsto e_3\mapsto e_1+e_2$. So on the permuted basis $[e_2,e_1,e_3]$ it is the companion matrix of the polynomial $X^3-X-1$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots of that polynomial, one (irrational positive) real and two complex conjugate ones (the expressions for them are too horrible to write down here). A basis of eigenvectors for these eigenvalues will do (and the first vector of your answer *must* be such an eigenvector). Not easy to find explicitly.

Since this is not the kind of things they usually ask you to do, you might want to check that you did not mistype the matrix.